# find limit points for the given trig function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

$$-5 \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{n}\right); \;n\in \mathbb{N}$$

The limit points are given as $$\pm 5(\sqrt{3}/2) , 0$$

I don't understand how these values come up. If anyone has a clue please help me understand it. 
kind regards.

Comment: Consider the subsequences (i) $n=3k$ (ii) $n=3k+1$ and (iii) $n=3k+2$. You will get all three limit points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using the trigonometric identities:

we have $$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}+\frac 1n\right)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right).$$

As $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad |\cos(x)|\leq 1,~x\in\mathbb R,$$ we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right) =0.$$

Now: for $n\in\mathbb N$ it should be fairly easy to calculate $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$ and with $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$$ we are done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The limit points are $\;\Bigl\{5\sin \dfrac{n\pi}3\:\bigg\vert\:  n\in\mathbf Z\Bigr\}$. How many values independent of $n$ does this make?